# C# TCPListener Simple issue

Tags: c#, wpf, tcpclient, tcplistener

I have this code, this is a simple WPF TcpListener application. below code works fine. 
but when i add codes in void Client() to Button_Click() event it does not work!. I don't understand the reason for this.
Can anyone explain to me please?.

This code runs fine :

```
    TcpClient client;
    NetworkStream ns;
    BinaryReader bRead;
    BinaryWriter bWrite;

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Task t = new Task(new Action(() =>
        {
            Server();
        }));
        t.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        Client();
    }

    public void Client()
    {
        client = new TcpClient(Dns.GetHostName(), 2055);
        ns = client.GetStream();
        bRead = new BinaryReader(ns);
        bWrite = new BinaryWriter(ns);
        bWrite.Write("entered");
        bWrite.Flush();


        bWrite.Write("entered");
        bWrite.Flush();
    }

    public void Server()
    {
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(2055);
        listener.Start();
        TcpClient CL = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
        NetworkStream ns = CL.GetStream();
        BinaryReader bread = new BinaryReader(ns);
        BinaryWriter bwrite = new BinaryWriter(ns);

        while(true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("waiting...");
            string res = bread.ReadString();
            MessageBox.Show(res);
        }
}
```

This codes is not responding when click button Button_click():

```
    TcpClient client;
    NetworkStream ns;
    BinaryReader bRead;
    BinaryWriter bWrite;

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Task t = new Task(new Action(() =>
        {
            Server();
        }));
        t.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        Client();
    }

    public void Client()
    {
    }

    public void Server()
    {
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(2055);
        listener.Start();
        TcpClient CL = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
        NetworkStream ns = CL.GetStream();
        BinaryReader bread = new BinaryReader(ns);
        BinaryWriter bwrite = new BinaryWriter(ns);

        while(true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("waiting...");
            string res = bread.ReadString();
            MessageBox.Show(res);
        }
}

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        client = new TcpClient(Dns.GetHostName(), 2055);
        ns = client.GetStream();
        bRead = new BinaryReader(ns);
        bWrite = new BinaryWriter(ns);
        bWrite.Write("entered");
        bWrite.Flush();


        bWrite.Write("entered");
        bWrite.Flush();
    }
```

Comment: Have you debugged your work?

Comment: @DonA i did. when i click the button nothing happens.

Comment: What does `Dns.GetHostName()` return?

Comment: The TcpListener constructor you are using is marked as *obsolete* according to the documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1y2a362e.aspx  That could be part of your problem.

Comment: @sircodesalot It returns my computer's host name correctly. just a string.

Comment: @TrevorElliott I did that according to `sircodesalot` 's answer. nothing happens

Comment: Put breakpoints at the start of your Button_Click and Server methods, are they being hit?  Step through those methods line by line.  Does it get stuck on a line?  Which line?  You need to apply some basic debugging here, saying "nothing happens" doesn't fly.

Comment: @TrevorElliott I fixed it. there was something else. Thanks man i kind of forgot breakpointing.